# Understanding Secondary Indexes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

if i have Table
Table

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    userId STRING(36) NOT NULL,
    contactName STRING(300) NOT NULL,
    eMail STRING(100) NOT NULL,
    ....
) PRIMARY KEY (userId)
```

and secondary index

```
CREATE NULL_FILTERED INDEX ActiveUsersByEMail 
ON Users (
    eMail,
    isActive,
)
```

and i select record by:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE eMail = 'test@test.com' AND isActive = TRUE
```

spanner will automatically look at index, take userId and give me a record ?.

or i need to create

```
CREATE NULL_FILTERED INDEX ActiveUsersByEMail_01 
ON Users (
    eMail,
    isActive,
    userId
)
```

and first take userId by:

```
SELECT userId from Users@{FORCE_INDEX=ActiveUsersByEMail_01} WHERE eMail = 'test@test.com' AND isActive = TRUE
```

and then i take a record by:

```
`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userId = '${userId}'``
```

Question is automatically use or not spanner secondary indices for standard select if condition match secondary index keys?

Comment: Note that you should be able to see how Spanner is executing your query (using the index or the main table) by asking it for the plan.  This can be doing via the QueryMode option in the executeSql method (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/executeSql ), or via the web interface when running a Query on the database.

Answer (score 2):

You should use FORCE_INDEX as Cloud Spanner will only choose an index in rare circumstances as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#index_directive). You can use the [STORING](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/secondary-indexes#storing_clause) clause to add data directly to the index, allowing you to read the data directly from the index to avoid the second call. This is suggested for common query patterns in your application.

Comment: This means also that: if in the select i include just only key columns  spanner again read the data directly from the index to avoid the second call?

Answer (score 0):

In [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2176) i ask same question and It turned out that this is easily done (without creating additional index) by:

```
SELECT * from Users@{FORCE_INDEX=ActiveUsersByEMail} WHERE eMail = 'test@test.com' AND isActive = TRUE
```

At this time the search is going on index and row come with all fields